# Using retrofit how can i add path param in url

Tags: android, retrofit

```
http://domain.com/5729e7aee4b0f52e476419c0
```

How can i add this part `5729e7aee4b0f52e476419c0` using Retrofit?

Comment: This is explained in the docs, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: use the @Path annotation

Comment: check out http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: @POST(url+"/{param}") Call<ClassName> function(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,@Path("param") String param); did this not working, i am using retrofit 2. can someone please point out the exact issue

Answer (score 5):

Just do like this

```
@POST("/method_name/{param}")
public void methodName(@Path("param") String id, Callback<Response> responseCallback);
```

Comment: What is this responseCallback?

Comment: Response you are receving from server but Response is an object you may define your Response Object..

Comment: Is that specific to retrofit 1? I use retrofit 2 and have not seen this

Comment: it is in retrofit 1.5

Comment: that's not retrofit2.

Comment: @POST(url+"/{param}")
        Call<ClassName> function(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,@Path("param") String param); did this not working, i am using retrofit 2.